# Adding text to ArcGIS Javascript layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I am using the ArcGIS Javascrit SDK for a basic user case of placing some markers with text on a map.  I am able to add the marker, but I am running into issues inserting text on that marker.

Here is my code:

```
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/dijit/BasemapToggle",
    "esri/dijit/LocateButton",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
     "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", 
     "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", 
     "esri/symbols/Font",
     "esri/symbols/TextSymbol", 
     "esri/Color",
    "esri/graphic", 
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  Map, BasemapToggle, LocateButton, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Font, TextSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Color, Graphic, GraphicsLayer
)  {
      map = new Map("map", {
        center: [mapval[0][2],mapval[0][1]],
        zoom: 18,
        basemap: "streets"
      });

        map.on("load", function() {
            var gl = new GraphicsLayer();
            var font = new Font("20px", Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.VARIANT_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_BOLDER);
            for (var i=0;i<mapval.length;i++){
                    var p = new Point(mapval[i][2], mapval[i][1]);
                    var s = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 20,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                        new Color([255,0,0]), 1),
                        new Color([0,255,0,0.25]));
                    var g = new Graphic(p, s);
                    g.setAttributes({
                        name: mapval[i][0]
                    });
                    gl.add(g);

                    var t = new TextSymbol(mapval[i][0],font, new Color([0, 0, 0]));
                    var g2 = new Graphic(p, t);
                    gl.add(g2);
            }


            map.addLayer(gl);                   
        });

  var toggle = new BasemapToggle({
    map: map,
    visible: true,
    basemap: "satellite"
  }, "BasemapToggle");
  toggle.startup();

  var geoLocate = new LocateButton({
    map: map
  }, "LocateButton");
  geoLocate.startup();

});
```

Comment: This code does not run as is because mapval is undefined. If you could update this to include mapval and post it in JSFiddle or Codepen then it may be easier for people to test it out and help you find the issue.

Comment: good catch.  mapval was a multi-dimensional array that was set higher in the code containing: {[Title,Lat,Lng]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SimpleLineSymbol in the require is in the wrong spot.  Once that was corrected to align with the functions then the label was displayed.